# Send method return type as generic

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, redis

I have some problem with redis generic caching because redis stores values as json and I have to deserialize it into my models but I can not because I'm using generic methods and I couldnt manage to solve this problem.

Redis get operations:

```
 public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var result = default(object);
        RedisInvoker(x => { result = x.Get<object>(key); });
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
        var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result.ToString(), settings);
        return deserializedObj;
    }
  public object Get(string key)
    {
        var result = default(object);
        RedisInvoker(x => { result = x.Get<object>(key); });
        return result;
    }
```

Caching Interception :

```
  public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodName = string.Format($"{invocation.Method.ReflectedType.FullName}.{invocation.Method.Name}");
        var arguments = invocation.Arguments.ToList();
        var key = $"{methodName}({string.Join(",", arguments.Select(x => x?.ToString() ?? "<Null>"))})";
        if (_cacheManager.IsAdded(key))
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = _cacheManager.Get(key);
            return;
        }
        invocation.Proceed();
        _cacheManager.Add(key, invocation.ReturnValue, _duration);
    }
```

What I want to do is get the method's returnType which is also generic and send it to Get method with generic type. But I couldn't send it like this :

```
 var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
        if (_cacheManager.IsAdded(key))
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = _cacheManager.Get<returnType>(key);
            return;
        }
```

The error is:

> returnType is a variable but used like a type

Comment: `if (invocation.Method.IsGenericMethod()) methodName+="<"+string.Join(",",invocation.Method.GetGenericArguments().Select(a => a.Name))+">";` or something...

Comment: To call `Get<T>` you'll need to `methodinfo.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(...)`. It's easier to add a `.Get(Type t, ...)` method instead.

Comment: Can you reply with complete answer please, I could not understand :/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to call `.Get<T>` with a type that you only know at runtime. The easy answer is; "don't". Instead create a non-generic method that you can call easily;

```cs
public object Get(Type type, string key) {...}
public T Get<T>(string key) => (T)Get(typeof(T), key);
```

Because the alternative involves reflection;

```cs
invocation.ReturnValue = typeof(...)
    .GetMethod("Get")
    .MakeGenericMethod(returnType)
    .Invoke(instance, new object[]{ key });
```

Comment: "The easy answer is; "don't"" - I'd say the answer is to use reflection. I wouldn't say "don't".

Comment: Because it's an XY Problem. "I want to do X", "Well the easy answer is actually Y".

Comment: What do you mean by that? How does that apply here?

Comment: A typical XY Problem paraphrased; "I've painted myself into this corner, and now I think I need to solve this problem". Ok answer; "While that problem is hard, here's how you solve it". Better answer; "Don't paint yourself into that corner, solve this problem instead". Note that I did both...

Comment: I know what an XY problem is. I just don't see how it applies here?